# Unsure how to compare the total works that each mass experiences in this problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

[image]

I tried going about this problem by drawing a Free body diagram
I find the work done on the 8kg mass is $$W_{Ft} + W_{Ff}$$
And for the 6kg mass $$W_{Ft} + W_{mg}$$

Now I have two main confusions about how to go on from here, one is solving for the tension so I can actually move on and solve the problem (Although I'm not sure if this is the right approach so far)

But I'm a bit lost because I always thought that the tension that pulls on the $8kg$ block is different (in magnitude/direction) than the tension that pulls on the $6kg$ block. But it turns out they are equal so using a free body diagram on the $6kg$ block would tension be  $T= -ma + mg$? If so I'm still kind of unsure how to compare the total work.

Another thought I had would be to look at total work as $$W_{tot} = \Delta K$$ but cant this formula be only applied to the $8kg$ block and not the $6kg$ block since it is hanging?

I feel like I'm over thinking these problems, the answer is apparently A.

Comment: 1.)  $ma$ is not a force.   2.) There is no mention os friction in the problem.  I wouldn't include friction.

Comment: @garyp well I was trying to say that because on the hanging block the the equation should be $T+6*(g) = 6a$ so is it wrong to say tension would equal  $T= -6(a) + 6(g)$

Comment: I see.  No, that's not wrong.   BTW, your idea of using the work-kinetic energy theorem sounds like a good idea.  Just remember that it applies only to systems with no internal (potential) energy.

Comment: @garyp Okay but how would I know that there is no potential energy involved for the hanging mass? It is hanging so does it not experience potential energy?

Comment: The hanging mass itself, taken as a system, has no potential energy.    Potential energy is *undefined* for single objects.  It's only defined for *pairs* of objects.  If you leave the Earth out of the definition of your system, then there is no potential energy to speak of.  The influence of the Earth becomes an *external force* and does work on the system.

Comment: @garyp so if there is no mention of the earth or potential energy of any kind. Then there is no potential energy? Even if an object's weight comes from the force of gravity?

Comment: Right.   If you isolate your attention to the hanging mass alone, gravity does work just as tension does.  No potential energy.

Comment: @garyp Okay that makes sense it just sounds kind of weird.

Answer (score 2):

Work is defined as the integral $\int_{x_0}^{x_1}F\cdot dx$ and when the motions are constrained to the same direction as the forces applied, it's just $\int_{x_0}^{x_1}Fdx$.

ignoring force and work for a second, assuming that the string is inextensible and the pulley and table are frictionless [assumptions that, while they seem necessary aren't actually stipulated in the question] the two masses must have the same magnitude of acceleration, some acceleration $a$. Otherwise, the length of the string would have to change or it'd become slack which makes no sense in this system.

$F = ma$, thus $a = \frac{F}{m}$, so then $F$ of the 8kg block must be greater than the force applied to the lighter block in order to have them accelerate at the same rate. It should then be clear that since they'd move the same magnitude of distance together, that the integral for the 8kg block is greater than that of the 6kg block.

However, to be a pain and a pedant, I would argue that E is the correct answer, since we don't actually *know* that the string is inextensible or that the pulley is frictionless.

Comment: Typically, in a problem like this, when they leave out things like friction and tension, that means they are negligible. I think you are correct to say that the answer is A.  The heavier block moving the same distance as the lighter block implies that more work was done on it.

Comment: Perhaps, but I also enjoy being more fallacious and taking things like this seriously rather than leaving them implicit. Plus in my experience [maybe a difference between UK and US / Wherever this is] it's stated explicitly.

Comment: The moving 2cm comment too could just be referring to a minimum value for both, indeed if the string could extend, they would have different actual distances. Once again, not really arguing that's what they mean, just playing with the statements